# How should I get the user submitted input?

Tags: 8, forms

On an submission handler, should I fetch the user input via `\Drupal::request()->request->get()` or is `$form_state->getValues();` the better (more saver) way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$request->request->all() != $form_state->getValues()

$request->request->all() === $_POST
$request->query->all() === $_GET
```

See in `Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder::buildForm()`

```
$input = $form_state->isMethodType('get') ? $request->query->all() : $request->request->all();
$form_state->setUserInput($input);
```

**$form_state->getValues()**  is already modified data that is formed on the basis of $form_state['input'] and #default_value

See in `Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder::handleInputElement();`

Pay attention to `#value_callback` it forms the value of the field

Comment: Thanks Mykola!  

Yep, I missed to check the code in: `Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder::buildForm()` .

Now I got it, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're doing, but the answer is probably [$form_state->getValues()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AgetValues/8.5.x) or [$form_state->getValue()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateValuesTrait.php/function/FormStateValuesTrait%3A%3AgetValue/8.5.x). There is also [$form_state->getUserInput()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AgetUserInput/8.5.x), but as you'll see on that page, it recommends you use one of the first 2 options unless you have a specific reason and know what you're doing.